# What should I do when it says 'Server white-listed'?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I set my username without spaces but it still says 'Server white-listed'. What should I do to join the server?

Comment: You username has nothing to do with white listing. If you are trying to join a server that is white listed it means you have to be on the white list. If its your own server, you can use the console to op yourself and then whitelist yourself (ops are automatically whitelisted)

Answer (score 8):

When a server is white-listed, it means that only the players on the white-list can access the server. This option is normally used if the owner of the server wants to limit which players can access their server.

The list of white-listed players can be found under `white-list.txt` in the root server directory. If you own the server, you can add yourself to this white-list to gain access to the server. (Please note that if you are an OP on the server you should already be white-listed).

If you are not the owner of the server, have a look at their website. Some servers require you to sign up on their website to be white-listed on the server.

If all else fails, contact the server owner directly.

Answer (score 2):

Since Mojang supports name changes, whitelisted players and their UUIDs are stored in `whitelist.json`.
If it's your server and you have access to the server console, use the command `whitelist add <YourMinecraftName>` or if you want to disable it, use `whitelist off`.
If it's not your server, try to contact the server owner and ask him to put you on the whitelist.